# Kudan Unity shadowcatcher

Tags: kudan

Im implementing a shadow catcher Kudan AR tracking scene based on the Kudan "My first Augmented Reality App" example tutorial for an IOS device.
I have a directional light, a 3d object and a ground plane with the kudan shadowcatcher material. The camera track is working and the 3dobject is effected by the directional light but I dont see a shadow on the ground plane. 
Has anyone tried this successfully?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not forum. Your question doesn't meet the standard of questions in stack overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more information on how to ask a question.

Comment: The ShadowCatcher object does not work in the current version of the Plugin. It's something we are working on. For now, it is possible to generate shadows on a regular plane or other object. If you ever have any luck rendering a shadow on a transparent surface, be sure to let us know.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.

Comment: Actually Im having trouble getting any shadows to appear. Im running on a Ipad Mini with IOS 9.3 compiled with a Macbook Pro running OSX El Capitan with Unity 5.3.5f1. Are there specific light types or project settings required?

Comment: I forgot to mention the shadows do appear in the Unity editor viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I got general shadow casting with a directional light. The problem was the Unity default project quality level for IOS was set to "simple" which had shadows turned off. I had to increase shadow distance settings and bias as well relative to my scene scale.
Now to try to get the Kudan shadowcatcher shader included in the Kudan Unity bundle going.

Comment: Ok I just applied the Kudan shadowcatcher shader to my ground plane and it works fine. So it was all because I wasn't setting the Unity shadow quality settings correctly for my IOS device.